# How would I map the entire source object A to a property of destination object B using Orika mapper?

Tags: java, orika

I would like to map the following two classes using Orika:

```
public class PagedList<T> extends ArrayList<T> {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@JsonProperty("total")
private Integer total;

@JsonProperty("offset")
private Integer offset;

@JsonProperty("count")
private Integer count = PagingService.PAGE_SIZE_DEFAULT_VALUE;

...
```

and

```
public class ListUsersResult {

    private List<UserDto> users;
    private Integer total;
    private Integer offset;
    private Integer pageSize;

    ...
}
```

so that the entire `PagedList` ends up in `users` property on `ListUsersResult` along with `total`, `object` and `pageSize`. I only see ways of mapping fields/properties from source to destination. Ideally I would like not to use `customize` method.